# What does 'hex' or 'oct' in Perl do when you pass in a hexadecimal or octal literal (instead of its string expression)?

Tags: perl, hex

For example, running

```
print hex("0x1234"), "\n";  # line1: Equivalent to hex("1234") or hex(1234)
print hex(0x1234), "\n";    # line2: What does this line do?
print hex(4660), "\n";      # line3: Equivalent to hex('4660') or hex('0x4660')
```

The code above would produce:

```
4660
18016
18016
```

So line2 is equivalent to line3. I was putting 4460 in line3 instead of 4660 to cause myself confusion. Thanks to all the replies that corrected my original mistake.

Comment: I think you meant the third line to be `print hex(4660), "\n";` instead of `print hex(4460), "\n";`. Then the output would have been `4660`, `18016`, `18016`

Comment: Sorry about the typo. Now it is all clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hex and oct take strings as operands.  If you give them a number, the number is first converted to a string.  print() does exactly the same thing.  If you say:

```
print 0x1234
```

it takes the number (4660), converts it to a string ("4660") and prints it.

Similarly, with:

```
hex(0x1234)
```

`hex` takes the number (4660), converts it to a string ("4660"), then interprets that as hexidecimal and returns that number (0x4660 = 18016).  When you print that, you get "18016".

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
$ perl -E "say 0x1234"
4660
$ perl -E "say 0x4660"
18016
```

4660 in base 10 is the same number as 1234 in base 16. 18016 in base 10 is the same number as 4660 in base 16.

So your first line converts the base-16 number in the string `"0x1234"` to a number.

Your second line turns the number 0x1234/4660 into the string `"4660"` and converts that base-16 number.

Your third one uses `4460` instead of `4660`, which I suspect is a typo.